# Restore view in List

Tags: list-view, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, restore

My customer changed the calendar list view "/MyItems.aspx". He changed the webpart on the page. Now he wants to restore it.

The problem is the myItems page contains some SharePoint magic with a back and forth button.

There is no backup and they can't use SharePoint Designer.

Is there a way to restore the view?

Comment: Don't you have regular content database backups or sharepoint backups? If you have then restore it to a temporary sitecollection/webapplication and find out the webparts in that view and modify the existing view and make similar changes

Comment: The site collection was created and modified on staging. Then it was copied to prod. Staging got no backup strategy.

Comment: In staging does the view works as expected? If yes then edit the view page and find out what settings it has

Comment: It is already broken in staging. They brought the errors to prod.